# Is there a way to start Explorer from a rollback custom action in WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Because of some dependencies, we close Windows Explorer during part of our installation.  As an emergency safety, I'd like to make sure that the user has a shell if we fail.  I thought that a type 34 custom action with 'Execute="rollback"' was what I wanted to do, but I don't seem to be smart enough to craft the CA.

Here's what I have:

```
<CustomAction Id="RestartExplorer"     
   ExeCommand="explorer.exe"
   Execute="rollback"
   Impersonate="yes"
   Return="asyncNoWait"/>
```

I know I'm missing a directory element, but I don't know how to specify a platform agnostic way of specifying %windir%\system32.  Using environment variables or scripting is not an option.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to kill Explorer during an install.  Doesn't it autorestart?  What if it restarted while you were installing?

Otherwise, if I did do this, I'd start it back up using the [QuietExec custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm).

You would also want to start it as an immediate custom action after InstallFinalize.  Note I didn't say commit because rollback can be disabled and commit wouln't execute.

Also the [SystemFolder property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you are looking for.  Make sure you test this on 32 and 64 bit machines.

Comment: Thanks.  We decided that restarting Explorer was bad manners so we've made it a user-driven action.

Answer (score 0):

Killing explorer is the wrong thing to do in any case that I can think of.  Instead of restarting explorer, I fixed the bug in our shell extension ;)  Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry Dude that's bullshit. You have to restart explorer in order to load the shell extensions immediately after install.